# How to see if a column ever has a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Agency Table that has `visitstartime` and `visitendtime` columns (These fields are `varchar(50)` even though it says is a date field. There are NO `NULLS`) I want to find out if a Agency never had a visit.
If i do:

```
SELECT * FROM AGENCY WHERE visitstartime = ' ' and visitendtime = ' '
```

It only returns RECORDS that are blank, but the same Agency could have Visits and have the field populated. How can I see the Agencies that didn't have any visits at all.

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?

Comment: SQL Server (SSMS v.18)

Comment: Are you sure the fields aren't `NULL`? What happens you try? And what are the values for the visit times in an instance where a visit did not occur?

Comment: So there's one record in the table per visit?

Comment: @JerryM. Positive there are no nulls. If the visit did not occur value is (Blank or Space) If I try to select IS NULL I get no records found.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yes. But an agency could have multiple visists

Comment: You can use an `EXISTS`

Comment: @HoneyBadger How can I use EXISTS?

Comment: You say "the same agency", how do you identify the different agencies?

Comment: @HoneyBadger The Agency has an AgencyID so the same AGENCY (Same Agencyid) could repeat multiple times that have and don't have visits. The I would see another Agency with different Agencyid that does he same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your table should be called visit rather than agency, but I guess you already noticed some design issues (like the datatype). Anyway, for your problem you can use something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    AGENCY as ag
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM  AGENCY as ag2
                  WHERE ag2.Agencyid = ag.Agencyid
                   AND ag2.visitstartime <> '' 
                   AND ag2.visitendtime  <> ''
                )
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like it worked. Will do some analyzing now to see if we got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT AgencyId
FROM AGENCY 
GROUP BY AgencyId
HAVING MAX(visitstartime) = ' ' AND
       MAX(visitendtime) = ' ';
```

You appear to be storing date/time values as a string.  I strongly recommend that you change your data structure to use an appropriate native date/time type.